# IPFS, blockchain and file searching questions

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

I'm an absolute beginner in the field and had a couple of questions that I'm really looking forward to having answers to.

1. Is IPFS a distributed or a decentralized file system? Which one of these options is more suitable to file systems in general?
2. Is there a record of all the hashes on the ipfs network? How does my request travel through the network?
3. How could blockchain fit in with IPFS? Has it been implemented already?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming related question and will benefit from a search engine

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System

Answer (score 0):

If we become an interplanetary species, IPFS could be the protocol we use to communicate with each other. It is a new protocol that could upgrade the entire internet.

HTTP protocol is the most popular on the internet. You know how you go to a website and it says HTTP at the beginning of URL bar. That's becoz your web browser is using the HTTP protocol to retrieve the page and this protocol was created by Tim Berners Lee in 1989. It defines two entities : A client and a Server. If the request was succesfull, a response is sent back so when you type in http://google.com in your browser which is the client, it uses http to request the Google main page and google's server uses http to send it to you as a response. This protocol is the backbone of world wide web. But http is not good enough anymore, infact it is totally broken and made the web completely centralised. These centralised servers are getting mor and more powerful by absorbing all of our data. Servers are given a unique IP address which define it's location. And becoz data is location addressed, if that location gets shutdown. That data is lost forever. But may be we could make a permanent web. A web where links never die. That's the vision of IPFS. It's peer to peer protocol, there is no central entity. People connect to each other directly. That means if you built a website on IPFS, it could never be shutdown by anyone, even if the government shuts down the internet during protests. People could still communicate with each other offline with IPFS and data would be owned by us, the people (not by any group). And becoz it's peer to peer so data transfer is much faster. The network gives data a content address, not an ip address so if you want to load a website, instead of your computer requesting from server across the world, it will find the nearest copy and your computer would retrieve it from there directly and if multiple people have copies of it, your computer would request it from all of them at the same time. The more peers, the faster the download. Videos would load so much faster. You could download the games 10 times faster. It is just better in every way.